# Fitting Log Logistic 4 parameter Mixed Model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, blocking, dose-response

I have a set of experimental growth data where I exposed a group of animals to increasing concentrations of multiple toxicants.
Two toxicants were run at a time in batches due to material considerations.
I observed log-logistic dose-response relationships and fit a four parameter model to each using the R *drc* package (Ritz 2015).
However, during analysis I saw that there were likely batch effects causing differences in control growth accross batches, which may skew my comparisons of the toxicants.
My initial thought for a model was to analyze using a hierachrical/mixed effects non-linear model such as

$Y_i = c_{j[i]} + \frac{d_{j[i]} - c_{j[i]}}{1 + \exp(b_{j[i]}\log(x) - \log(e_{j[i]}))} + \epsilon_{j[i]}$

for every $i$ toxicant in batch $j$. Please forgive any bad notation, I am certainly a biologist.

However, I am not familiar with the necessary R packages to test this and am still rather new to non-linear mixed effects models. My questions are,

1. Assuming I haven't missed the mark entirely on this, is this model sufficient to analyze and compare batches in this dataset?
2. If this is the correct way to go about this, which functions should I use to fit and assess the model in R?
   I am still new and am not familiar with mixed effects modeling outside of what Gelman and Hill (2007) covers.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/510158/212798  You can adapt the answer to your situation by treating batch as a fixed effect in the $X \beta$.  If you really want to have batch be a mixed effect, it is a little more complicated than the example.

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly an option but I was more looking for a way to model changes in the parameters between batches. I ultimately have decided to go with the work discussed by [Ritz et al.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4539407) and with their suggested analyses for non-similar dose-response curves. This solution works best for my use case. However, I would encourage anyone who finds themselves in this situation to also check out that answer linked above in the first comment.